# How would I divide up this vector map in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, maps

So I just traced out a map of Westeros using Illustrator's pen tool, what I want to do is divide the map into the different "provinces" or kingdoms. In other words, how do I draw the borders on the map and then be able to have an independent area on the map that I can color differently.. does this make sense?

I tried to use delete anchor point tool to draw the borders from the gap to then close the gap again, it works but there's gotta be a better way? if you can tell me what that better way is, I'd be so grateful!!

[image: Map in Illustrator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Take my (similarly well made...) map of Westeros

[image]

### Draw your Kingdom's borders

[image]

### With everything selected, use the Shape Builder Tool (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)

[image]

### Select each Kingdom and color as you wish

[image]

### Westeros!

[image]

Comment: THAANK YOUU! .. and yea your map is much better than mine.. so jealous!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the Pathfinder's `Divide` tool. Open the Pathfinder panel with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

1. Draw the provinces as paths dividing Westeros, and make sure those lines overlap.
2. Select everything and click on divide. You can then cleanup and style the different Kingdoms separately.

`NB: Protip, to get the best cleanup effect make sure you don't recolor/refill Winterfell, the default white will do just fine`